# Actionscript/Flex not having native JSON parsing abilities?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have done some searching around, and from what it looks like so far, there is no native way to parse JSON in Actionscript/Flex. XML is automagiaclly parsed and life is good. Why isn't JSON parsed this same way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Native JSON parsing is a part of Flash Player 11. You can look at the [API in the docs.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) For earlier versions, you'll have to use a library, like [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json) to parse JSON.

Comment: Please have a look at a similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667291/how-to-decode-json-using-native-json-or-actionjson-in-flex-3). Thanks